# Struts2 pass objects between actions

Tags: java, object, struts2, action

I am newbie here and posting first time...I have one question to ask, in struts2 I want to pass objects/data between actions while implementing session. Let us say I have action A which has a String called "myStr" or even an object called myObj, then how can i make it available in whole session while passing between actions? actionA-->calls actionB--> actionC..blah blah...but the value of myStr or myObj has to be accessed in any of action class. Would you please guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values when using REQUEST attributes.

When you put attributes in the SESSION, they will stay there for the lifetime of the session (unless you explicitly remove them).

Anytime, anywhere, until the session is valid, you will retrieve them by calling `session.get("myKey")`